# android upload xml file to google drive or dropbox

Tags: android, xml

i have some xml for my app, and I want upload it to google drive or dropbox for parse xml from url.
but how to upload it with url like http://.../name.xml or http://.../name/?format=xml.
thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-You can post the xml to your cloud service of choice.

-Get the link of the file.

-Shorten the link here: [Bit.do](http://bit.do/)

-Then Customize your short link to something like **example.xml**

-The result will be bit.do/example.xml